How to properly switch between firebase projects to build for web?
I have two projects that I setup for my firestore + flutter project. I am trying to switch between building / deploying to them by using the firebase use command.
However, when I initialize my app in my main.dart, I pass in options because if I don't pass them in, it fails. But those options don't change when I switch between project using firebase use - so the same project always gets built into my app regardless.
How am I supposed to be setting this up?

I think you need to run flutterfire configure every time you want to switch projects. This will regenerate your firebase_options.dart file which contains project references.
See https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup for more details
